# Senator bicycle

Tags: touring, road

I own a bicycle by the name Senator, manufactured in Austria, by the Senator company.  I have had the bike for over 35 years.  I Would like to find out any information on it.

Comment: Do you have any photos of the bike? Or do you want info on the company? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: You need to provide more details about the bike if you want more information. You might also find more information if you know people in AUstria in teh bicycle industry if it was a decently sized brand there.

Comment: I'd start by googling "senator bicycle austria" and this question is already the second highest match.

Comment: If you want to add two clearly lit and high res photos to your question, it will help future searchers to reach closure.

Comment: http://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/986689-senator-bicycle.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Senator is a store brand bike from the 70's.  They did rebadge Puch branded bikes which were made in Austria, as did Sears.

It probably has cottered cranks, a three speed internally geared hub, and a twist shifter on the handlebars.

If it has sentimental value then by all means rebuild it, but its not especially rare.  If you just want a bike to ride, it might be cheaper, less work, and give you a better ride to pick up a slightly used modern bike.